# Trying to find apt regex expression for my query

Tags: java, regex, string

```
Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("(?:^|)'([^']*?)'(?:$|)");    
Matcher m = p1.matcher(input);
//Matcher m = p2.matcher(testcases);                       
while (m.find()) {
    output += (m.group().replace("\'", "").trim() + "/");    
}
```

**Input**

> /content/folder[@name='folder query 2']/folder[@name='Share  file
>   Zone']/folder[@name='steve']/folder[@name="steve's Personal
>   Folder"]/folder[@name='Backup']/folder[@name='20150317']/folder[@name='.Archive']

output should be -

```
folder query 2, 
Share file zone, 
steve, 
steve's Personal folder, 
Backup, 
20150317,  
.Archive
```

for some reasons my regex expressions seems to be reading only words with quotes so it doesn't consider steve's neither double quotes of the same. i am trying to format the query hence what i  require is only folder names irrespective of single quote or double quote without considering apostrophe associated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get every thing between `[@name=['\"]` and `['\"]` your regex should look like this `\\[@name=['\"](.*?)['\"]]` :

```
Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("\\[@name=['\"](.*?)['\"]]");

Matcher m = p1.matcher(input);                      
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

**Output**

```
folder query 2
Share file Zone
steve
steve's Personal Folder
Backup
20150317
.Archive
```

## Ideone Demo

Comment: i also need the "steve's personal folder" in my output which is in double quotes.

Comment: The input text `"steve's Personal Folder"` is then matched with starting `"` and ending `'`, i.e. matches `steve` only.

Comment: @Andreas did you tried my solution or you just down-vote it? check the solution here https://ideone.com/Vq2v4F what it return ?

Comment: I guess I tried you very first version of the answer that didn't include the `[@name=` in the regex.

Comment: this is my answer from beginning @Andreas you can check the edits :)

Comment: @YCF_L I copy/pasted your code and it didn't work. Similarly, first comment here is about "steve's personal folder" not working, with followup by you that you fixed it. All that is not reflected in history, because you edited the answer within the first 5 minutes. So, there was a version of your answer where it didn't work, even though history doesn't reflect that.

Comment: Anyway, this code, while giving correct results, may still fail in the extremely rare instance of input like `[@name="abc[']xyz"]` because you don't verify that start and end quote are the same type of quote (single vs double). Using a backreference, like in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43899291/5221149), that problem can be eliminated.

Comment: my first version was like this `\\[@name='(.*?)']` i don't set the `"` and like you said i change it in the first 5 min because i find wrong @Andreas

Answer (score 4):

Use the following regex: `(['"])(.*?)\1`

It matches the opening quote (single or double), capturing that character as capture #1, captures the text as capture #2, and ends with the same kind of quote used at the beginning, by matching the capture #1.

Remember to escape `"` and `\` when writing as Java string literal.

*Test*

```
String input = "/content/folder[@name='folder query 2']/folder[@name='Share file Zone']/folder[@name='steve']/folder[@name=\"steve's Personal Folder\"]/folder[@name='Backup']/folder[@name='20150317']/folder[@name='.Archive']";
for (Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(['\"])(.*?)\\1").matcher(input); m.find(); )
    System.out.println(m.group(2));
```

*Output*

```
folder query 2
Share file Zone
steve
steve's Personal Folder
Backup
20150317
.Archive
```